# Service Unavailable Error from APIGATEWAY

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am using multiple lambdas in the step functions. The client hits the API gateway, which invokes a lambda, and that lambda invokes the step function's lambdas to get the response.

The response time is 3-7 seconds when lambdas are already warmed up.
But when it has cold-start, it takes more than 30 seconds for some requests based on input.

As the API gateway has a timeout of 30 seconds, I get a “503- service Unavailable error" for some requests request though the execution is running. Though AWS says, it should give 504 for request time out.

Then I used provisioned concurrency for the latency issue, which will likely solve the timeout issue. But still, sometimes, I get a service Unavailable error.

I checked cloudwatch trace. Interestingly, Each lambda takes an initialization time of 3 seconds even after provisioning. Now I doubt whether provisioned-concurrency is working or I do not understand it.

Any advice?

Comment: Provisioned concurrency seems to be working if after enabling it, it no longer takes 30 seconds on a cold start. Are you using Java by any chance? Which API integration are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am using python. My integration type in Apigateway is the Lambda function.

Comment: Also,  I checked the ProvisionedConcurrencySpilloverInvocations metric. It is 0.
That means the provision is working. But each lambda still takes 3 seconds for initialization. I can see this from cloudwatch trace.

Comment: What was the init time before provisioned concurrency was enabled? Does your lambda always invoke successfully, no errors? Was the integration proxy or non proxy?